# Javascript player for managing playlist of vimeo *and* youtube videos?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, vimeo

I'm a little curious. I have a list of vimeo videos which I play through an API, and I also have a list of youtube videos which I play via an API.

They are on my website.

What I'm trying to do is create a universal player which will combine vimeo and youtube videos into a single loop. Say when all vimeo videos have finished, continue and play the youtube videos.

I have literally no idea where to start other than it will require javascript.

Any ideas? Appreciate the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "They are on my website." ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your course of action should be:

1. Have a movie container positioned on your page
2. Look at first movie in your combined list
3. Instantiate the relevant player (YT or vimeo) using their javascript API ([Youtube](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html), [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js) ) inside the container.
4. Add an event listener for movie ended on the created instance (both APIs support it)
5. On movie ended event, clear the container
6. Move list itarator to next movie
7. Go to 2