# End events for embedded videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, vimeo

I'm trying to find a way to listen for the end/complete event of a video embedded from youtube/metacafe/vimeo etc. I know this can be accomplished by things like the youtube API using onStateChange with a value of 0, but I'm curious if it can be done without having to go through the API.

For example if I have something like:

```
<div id="video-container">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0Bmhjf0rKe8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

is there anyway I can listen for the end event on the div or iframe?

kind of like this:
[Javascript player for managing playlist of vimeo *and* youtube videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682287/javascript-player-for-managing-playlist-of-vimeo-and-youtube-videos) 
But I'm interested in adding several sources so it would be much easier if I didn't have to go through the APIs.

Thanks-

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think, it's not possible for youtube. It would be possible if you used your own flash player. You would be able to call custom javaScript function from yuor flash player.